# Can't mount second hard drive on CentOS 6.6 - Duplicate VG name

Tags: mount, hard-disk, automounting, ssd, duplicate

Yesterday I add a SSD to my PC configuration and I make on it a fresh installation. At the moment of installation I replace my old HDD and there was only the SSD. When the installation finish I make a manually shutdown to attach the HDD with cables and then turn on the pc. After that I can't open my information on the HDD but in BIOS everything seems fine. From second HDD I can mount only boot partition which is 524MB from 500GB HDD.

When I check with `fdisk -l` what is the situation the answer looks fine:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d66f4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       15567   124521472   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16481d17

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2              64       60802   487873536   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_andromeda-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_andromeda-lv_swap: 8136 MB, 8136949760 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 989 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_andromeda-lv_home: 65.7 GB, 65682800640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7985 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Here is a screenshot of **computer:///**
[image: screenshot]

When I execute `mount /dev/sdb2 /storage` as root

I get the following error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

When I run `vgs` here is the answer:

```
WARNING: Duplicate VG name vg_andromeda: Existing gc5zhX-vrW9-mEDA-mzNN-kZxf-9nON-1aWwGY (created here) takes precedence over bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73
WARNING: Duplicate VG name vg_andromeda: Existing gc5zhX-vrW9-mEDA-mzNN-kZxf-9nON-1aWwGY (created here) takes precedence over bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73
WARNING: Duplicate VG name vg_andromeda: gc5zhX-vrW9-mEDA-mzNN-kZxf-9nON-1aWwGY (created here) takes precedence over bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73
WARNING: Duplicate VG name vg_andromeda: gc5zhX-vrW9-mEDA-mzNN-kZxf-9nON-1aWwGY (created here) takes precedence over bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73
```

So can anyone helps me because I can't open my information from the HDD. I've tried to mount /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb2 (there is no problem with /dev/sdb1 because there is the boot partition).

On the fresh installation I use the same username and hostname as on the old. Also on the old HDD there is a other CentOS installation but there is a lot of information and I want copy it first to the SSD and then I'll format the HDD.

Best regards,
Georgi!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Volume group name should be unique on system, by design. Problem occurs when a disk is moved from one system to another.

So you have few options (detailed below)

- Rename the VG externally [not mounted] disk(s).
- Rename the VG of your system (not realistic)
- Merge both volume group into a single one (probably needs to rename first)

**Option 1 - Rename the VG externally on the unmounted disk(s)**

Use the command [vgrename](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgrename). You need to use [vgdisplay](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgdisplay) or [vgs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgs),to retrieve the volume group UUID.

```
$ vgs -o vg_name,vg_attr,vg_uuid
VG           Attr   VG UUID                               
vg_andromeda wz--n- gc5zhX-vrW9-mEDA-mzNN-kZxf-9nON-1aWwGY
????         ?????? bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73

$ vgrename bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73 vg_andromeda_old
$ vgchange -ay vg_andromeda_old
```

(please, edit/update this post with the actual ouput of the command vgs)

**Option 2 - Rename the VG of your system**

This is not realistic. You can't rename an active volume group, so you would have to boot on a CD/DVD, rename the VG, and fix your system configuration in various places (fstab, bootloader)...

However,  since your installation is fresh, you could reinstall your system with another name.

**Option 3 -  Merge both volume group into a single one**

You could merge both VGs, but it has a few caveats;

1. It only makes sense if both drives are meant to remain on the system.
2. You can't have two LVs with the same name in a single VG.
3. You have an SSD and an HDD, It's recommended to keep them on distinct VG for clarity.
4. The [vgmerge](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgmerge) command seems to only merge two VGs by Name (not UUID), so you have to rename the duplicate VG anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved with renaming of VolumeGroup. With this command:

```
vgrename bwQkRq-mgph-9BYf-9WPF-cKz0-FLFq-0Qxs73 storage
```